# How to make my Java SpringBoot application to proxy MQTT Broker WebSocket 8083 port?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, proxy, mqtt

Let's suppose we have a Java Spring Boot application called **A**. And we have another MQTT Broker and its 8083 port supports MQTT WebSocket.

Previously, the device directly connected to the MQTT Broker's 8083 port to obtain MQTT WebSocket service. Now, I want the device to connect to the **A** application's 8083 port (not MQTT Broker anymore) to obtain the MQTT WebSocket service.

I think **A** application should only be a program that implements TCP proxy, it does not really implement MQTT WebSocket. Which means any TCP packet that device send to **A** application 8083 port, should be sent to MQTT Broker 8083 port. And any TCP packet that MQTT Broker sends, should be sent to the device through **A** application.

In other words, I want the device connect to `ws://A_Application_host:8083/mqtt` should just work the same as connecting to `ws://MQTT_Broker_host:8083/mqtt`.

Do you know any solution or Java code that help me implements this? Any framework or Java code is OK.

Comment: nginx reverse proxy or github ( https://github.com/topics/websocket-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

By using io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap and io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap, it seems that it can meet my needs.

I would continue to work on it.

---

Another solution is this: [How to make my Java SpringBoot application to proxy MQTT Broker WebSocket 8083 port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74933226)